# Erro EmbeddedResource e references NuGet

Tags: xamarin

Meu caros,

Quando tento executar o programa de teste de ambiente disponibilizado no curso estou recebendo os erros :

> Error     Build action 'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more
>   of the project's
>   targets.  EnviarCorreo.Forms  C:\Users\DennisAraujo\Documents\Estudo
>   Informatica\xamarin\xamarin-ambiente-teste-master\xamarin-ambiente-teste-master\EjercicioBase\EnviarCorreo.Forms\EnviarCorreo.Forms\Views\MainPage.xaml
>
> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore

Windows 10 home
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
jdk 1.8.0_101
Xamarin update em dia

Comment: Sugiro melhorar a qualidade da sua pergunta para obter melhores respostas. Por exemplo, colocar o código da sua aplicação. Saiba mais sobre [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Valdrez, você tentou clicar com o botão direito na raiz do projeto e clicar com botão direito em Restore NuGet Packages ?

Comment: Junior, sim tentei fazer o restore NuGet e quando faço o Build recebo o erro mencionado. Participo da maratona Xamarin e foi disponibilizado um projeto para teste do ambiente, não alterei nada. Segue os código que apresentam os erros.

Comment: Segue os código que apresentam os erros.   App.xaml -> using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace EnviarCorreo.Forms 
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new EnviarCorreo.Forms.MainPage();
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            
        }


        {
         }
    }
}

Comment: Veja esta resposta em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111423/build-action-embeddedresource-is-not-supported-by-one-or-more-of-the-projects

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver com a solução proposta no link abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111423/build-action-embeddedresource-is-not-supported-by-one-or-more-of-the-projects